# JQuery ajax OPTIONS authorisation request not working

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, cors

I'd like to POST data to another domain and receive the confirmation message returned by the action. So to get CORS to work I've got an options action to handle the OPTION HTTP method (on the same path as the POST) in my rails controller, which currently looks like this:

```
def options
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '100'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*, x-requested-with, content-type, accept, origin, referer, user-agent'
  render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
end
```

My jquery ajax request looks like this: (coffeescript)

```
$.ajax
  type: 'POST'
  url:  'http://my-other-domain.com/'
  data: data
  contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  crossDomain: true
  success: (response) => 
    if response.data_saved
      ...
  error: () => ...
```

but... it don't work.

The OPTIONS request seems to be working, returning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` and all, the server receives and processes the POSTed data, but Chrome still throws

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my-other-domain.com/. Origin http://my-main-domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

in the console and fires the error callback.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header must be included on all responses, not just on the preflight OPTIONS response. Adding that header on the POST response should fix things.

(Also note that '*' is not a valid value in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, but it shouldn't break anything)

Comment: You're a life saver! None of the articles I read seemed to make this point (clearly).

Comment: Here's a flow chart that shows when each CORS header should be set: http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I had a problem like that , the cross ajax problem , in php I resolved that with header("..."); Then I started to use 
  `.getJSON`
 method in Jquery