# Pb when i try sign in with devise and ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, devise

i am encoding a chromium extension that connects to a ruby server in order to save or send a reminder notification when the time comes, the connection works and it is possible for the user to create a reminder (on our ruby server) since the extension. my problem is during the sign_in that I would like to be able to do since the extension in order to recover authanticity_token, when I send the request to the server I have an error in javascript console type:

```
XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in".
send @ jquery.js:4
ajax @ jquery.js:4
ajaxLogin @ log_in.js:26
(anonymous) @ log_in.js:13
dispatch @ jquery.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.js:3
11:39:05.127 Navigated to file:///home/eth3r/Bureau/WaltTest/walt-e/log_in.html
```

and in ruby's console :

```
Started OPTIONS "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-01 11:49:27 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/users/sign_in"):
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'sessions',
    registrations: 'registrations'
  }

  resources :reminders, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy, :index, :update]
  root to: 'pages#home'

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :reminders, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy, :index, :update]
    end
  end
end
```

**my ajax function :**

```
function ajaxLogin(email, password) {
    var data = {
      "user": {
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
      }
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: apiBaseUrl + "/users/sign_in",
      headers: ajaxHeaders,
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType : "application/json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, status, text) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(text);
        console.error(jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    });
  };
```

I've been on the same problem for two days now, javascript is horrible!

Comment: Show your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: it's ok for the route file

Comment: [`devise_for`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for) does not create the route for `OPTIONS`. Check your javascript and change `OPTIONS` request to `GET`, or [handle `OPTIONS` manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926908/how-to-respond-to-an-http-options-request).

Comment: now a get that :

Comment: yet POST works to create a new reminder

Comment: you have problem with your cors, this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621946/jquery-ajax-options-authorisation-request-not-working

Comment: you mean I have to set my server to return Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in these answers ?

Comment: because with postam the queries work

Comment: Sorry, my problem is that I use a link to submit the form instead of a button.